# Why is my "cd" command ignored in the windows XP command prompt?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

I'm trying to set a default path in the windows command prompt but my `CD` command seems to be ignored. I'm not getting any error/warning either. What am I doing wrong? The contents of the prompt -after 2 attempts- are:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Work>cd "D:\Downloads\xlrd-0.9.0.tar\dist\xlrd-0.9.0\x
lrd-0.9.0"

C:\Documents and Settings\Work>cd D:\Downloads\xlrd-0.9.0.tar\dist\xlrd-0.9.0\xl
rd-0.9.0

C:\Documents and Settings\Work>
```

Here's a screenshot of what has been going on:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/116120595/command_prompt_trouble.jpg

Comment: @Karan: you're right, that's the same misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `cd` command worked just fine, but you're still looking at the wrong drive.

Type: `d:` to switch to that drive.

Or, include `/D` to change the drive in addition to changing the folder:

```
cd /D D:\Downloads\xlrd-0.9.0.tar\dist\xlrd-0.9.0\xlrd-0.9.0
```

Comment: great, it's working now! But I don't really understand why. A path is just a path, right? Why am I looking at the wrong drive if I explicitly pointed to the D:\ drive? Or am I looking for logic where there isn't any?

Comment: True, but on Windows (and in the old MS-Dos) drives are really separated using that odd `c:` prefix. On Linux, for example, one would "mount" physical drives into the same file system path, where the path `/abc/123` could be a different harddisk than `/xyz/456`, which in Windows would then be `c:\123` and `d:\456`

Comment: On Windows every drive has its own path scope.

Answer (score 2):

This is intended behaviour for windows.

On just about any operating system 'cd' (change dir) changes to the new directory.

On windows it only does that for a volume, but it does not change to that volume.

If you are on the C: volume (as in your screenshot) and then do a `cd d:\foo` then you stay in your current folder. You will need to follow it up with `d:` to actually change to the newly set place.